# Excel - VLOOKUP to search two columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So here's what I'm trying to do. In my Backorder workbook, I have an Item # (this is either composed of a Manufacturer Part # or Retail Part #) and a Description of the part. Instead of hand typing in the description of each part, I was hoping to have it automatically populate based on the Item #. So I have a VLOOKUP equation that references my Inventory workbook, searching between the Manufacturer Part #, Retail Part #, and Part Description. It then returns the Part Description when found. My code looks something like this:

```
=VLOOKUP($G3, '[Finished Inventory.xlsx]Finish goods'!$E$2:$G$4000, 3, 0)
```

So I got this to work... but not without issue. The only rows returned with a proper value are the rows that contain a Manufacturer Part # (which is the first column searched through). But here's the weird part (to me at least): When I change my VLOOKUP range from 3 columns (Manufacturer Part #, Retail Part #, and Part Description) to 2 (Retail Part # and Part Description) I have much better results with having less #N/A cells. Issue is that now the parts with Manufacturer Part #s are left #N/A. Seems like VLOOKUP only searches through the first column of the search range.

So after typing this all out I'm realizing VLOOKUP only searches through one column... Can a solution be made such that it searches through two columns and returns a third?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to imitate a `=VLOOKUP` with two search columns and one result column, use something like this:

```
=(IFERROR(INDIRECT("C" & MATCH($D$12,A:A,0)),INDIRECT("C" & MATCH($D$12,B:B,0))))
```

> D12 is your input cell.

`INDIRECT` will take a textual string and turn it into a cell reference, and Match will find you a Row in a column where the first instance of that value is presence.

In this example Column A is searched first, if that returns an error, Column B is searched, in either case, the result is the matched row in Column C

a     - 1     - res1
b     - 2     - res2
c     - 3     - res3
d     - 4     - res4

In the above example, "c" entered into D12 will give us "res3" in our formula output, where "2" will give us "res2" and so on.

Comment: Heck yea you're the man, this worked perfectly. I have one minor issue: Some of my search values have spaces at the end and are resulting in a #N/A until I fix it. Is it possible to tailor this search so that it matches with "close enough" or must I go through and fix all of these?
Thank you!

Comment: Universal solution to any problem in excel: Make the formula longer `=(IFERROR(IFERROR(INDIRECT("C" & MATCH(D12,A:A,0)),INDIRECT("C" & MATCH(D12,B:B,0))), IFERROR(INDIRECT("C" & MATCH(D12 & " ",A:A,0)),INDIRECT("C" & MATCH(D12 & " ",B:B,0)))))`  This will only match for a single space though, I highly suggest just running a VBA macro to trim your search columns of whitespace.

Comment: I'm just going to run a macro seems better in the long run. If you have hand one that does this I'd appreciate it. If not I'll do some goolging. Thank you sir!